# I have 4 variable which value have in percentage and i want to remove percentage in all variable

Tags: php

I have 4 variable which value have in percentage and i want to remove percentage in all variable

```
$a = "25%";
$b= "47%";
$c = "8%";
$d= "14%";
```

Comment: Is it `$a="25%"` ?

Comment: why you added `%` and why do you want to remove it ?

Comment: If you are trying to apply arithmetical operation then you can apply directly without any change : https://eval.in/1064505

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a = str_replace('%', '', $a);
$a = intval($a);
```

Comment: My pleasure! :)

Comment: No need to use `str_replace` in this case only `intval` is enough : https://eval.in/1064497

Comment: Oh,yes, you're right!

Answer (score 0):

For % alone then you can just use the str_replace("%", "" ,$str);

otherwise you can use common function to remove special character like the below one

```
function formatStr($str) {
   $str = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphen values.
   $str = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $str); // Removes special characters.
   return preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $str); // Replaces multiple hyphens with single.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If % is always at the end of string use

```
rtrim($a, '%');
```

Comment: @ Nishant Saini Thanks